# Coordinates of P which lies on positive x axis

Tags: calculus

This is a question that I copied from -

Given that the tangent to the curve $y=x^3 -5x+7$ at point $P$ , which lies on the positive $x$-axis, is $3y-6x=15$ , find coordinates of $P$

I found P to be $(1,3) $

However , the question states 'positive x axis' meaning $P$ should be $(x,0)$ as $ y = 0$

Could this be a possible question error or am I missing out on something ?

Comment: The line $3y-6x=15$ is not tangent to the curve $y=x^3-5x+7$ at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=(x_0,y_0)$ and $f(x)=x^3-5x+7$.  The tangent at $P$ has the equation$y=2x+5$.

Compute $x_0$ and $y_0$ by the condtions:

$f'(x_0)=2$, $x_0 >0$ and $y_0=2x_0+5$